# What are methods for tracking discussions or issues on Drupal.org

Tags: community-official-site

On Drupal.org, there are a number of discussions or issues that I subscribe to and wish to track. Do folks use any particular method to receive push updates or alerts when replies are added to threads?

Is typing in "subscribe" still the only method for tracking discussions?

I dislike having to "check" on webpages to be notified of updates. I'm more of an RSS and Google Reader tracker.

Comment: The reason why many users leave a comment such as "subscribe" is that they subscribed to their issue reports, which include both the issue reports they created and the issue reports they commented to.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I subscribe that way often. how do you unsubscribe?

Comment: @Chris Go to the subscribing page for the project (e.g. http://drupal.org/project/issues/subscribe-mail/webmaster for the webmaster's queue), and select "None"; then click on "Subscribe."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[You can now track issues where you haven't posted comments](https://drupal.org/node/1306444). To track an issue, you can just click the *Follow* button now available to the sidebar.

> [image: Follow button]

Followed issues will show up on your Drupal.org account under *Your Posts*.

If you want to track *all* the issues for a project, there are a few additional options:

- You can subscribe by e-mail by going to a project page and clicking on *Subscribe via e-mail* under the *Issues for PROJECT* heading
- You can subscribe to an RSS feed if you go to the issue list for the project and click the link at the bottom of the list (but your reader should also autodiscover the feed)

Answer (score 5):

All issue queries have RSS feeds. I sometimes set up feedburner feeds with email notification when I want to get emails if something pops up in a particular category.

1. Create an issue query at http://drupal.org/project/issues
2. Grab the feed URL using your browser or whatever. For example, the feed url for all views issues in "Needs Review" is http://drupal.org/project/issues/search/rss?projects=Views&status[0]=8
3. Go to feedburner.google.com and create a feed there, and choose to send out email with new articles.

I'm sure there are other approaches that turn feeds into emails. This is just one I've used. This one is nice because you can share it with others.